# Get HTML Response From PHP In Fetch API

Tags: javascript, php, fetch-api

I want to send html code from my php backend to my JavaScript front end. I've did it in JQuery AJAX, but I want to do it in Fetch API. How Can I.

PHP Backend

```
if (isset($_POST)) {
  echo '<b>DataToSend</b>';
  // And More
}
return;
```

JavaScript Frontend

```
fetch('', {

  method: 'POST',
  body: data,

}).then(function(data){

  document.body.innerHTML = data;

});
```

data is going to Backend but not coming from it. I want to show html that php backend is returning.

Comment: You don't call any backend url..

Comment: @DavidAnsermot — Yes, they do. It's `''` a relative URL to the current page. (Suggestive of bad design, but not the actual problem)

Comment: @DreamBold — No. Look at the code in the question: `echo '<b>DataToSend</b>';`. That isn't JSON. Giving them an example that uses a different URL with a different data format that will error if they try to apply it to their own code is unhelpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [some examples of using fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch#examples).

The return value from `fetch(...)` is a promise that resolves to [a Response object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response).

This is **not** the parsed response body.

In your code, `data` is not your data, it is the response object.

You need to pick one of the [methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response#instance_methods) that handles the response body and use it (noting that it also returns a promise).

Since your server side code is outputting HTML that you try to interact with as if it were a string, you probably want to treat the body as plain text:

```js
const responsePromise = fetch('', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: data,
});
const bodyPromise = responsePromise.then(response => response.text());
bodyPromise.then(html => document.body.innerHTML = html);
```